# "Зачустраний". Що це за слово?

Tags: вживання-слів, невідоме-слово

У "Польових дослідженнях з українського сексу" О. Забужко є речення:

> — вона, котру млостi змагали на вид **зачустраних** рiдних алкашiв у
>   проплiшинах залишкової генiальности (кому цiкаво, ось адреси: "Еней" у
>   Києвi, "Червона калина" у Львовi, вхiд вiльний, годувати, а надто ж
>   поїти тварин не то дозволяється, а й заохочується), —

Тлумачні словники у 11 томах, словник Грінченка, російсько-українські словники не знаходять цього слова. Що воно значить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Відповідь на питання знаходимо через слово ["чустрати" у словнику Грінченка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%87%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8):

> ЧУСТРАТИ, -аю, -аєш, недок., перех., діал. Чухрати (у 1 знач.).
>
> ЧУХРАТИ, -аю, -аєш, недок. 1. перех. Обламувати, обрубувати гілля на
>   дереві, стовбурі; очищати від листя, кори. 2. перех. Чесати, очищати
>   вовну від домішок, сміття. 3. перех., розм. Завдавати ударів
>   кому-небудь, сильно бити, шмагати кого-небудь; дубасити, періщити. 4.
>   перен. Різко вичитувати, лаяти, докоряючи за кого-, що-небудь. 5.
>   неперех., розм. Енергійно рухатися, бігти, їхати, поспішаючи
>   куди-небудь. // Тікати від кого-небудь. 6. Швидко поширюватися,
>   охоплюючи щось, знищуючи його (про вогонь, полум'я).

І через [етимолоґічний словник української мови:](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Pivtorak_Hryhorii/Etymolohichnyi_slovnyk_ukrainskoi_movy_T_2_D_Koptsi/)

> [**зачустритися**] „захиріти, споганіти”, [зачустратися] „тс.”; неясне;
>   можливо, похідне від [чустрити] „бити, сікти”, зближеного з чухатися.

Отже, "зачустраний" - це "захирілий", "споганілий".